# AutoMapper - Mapping to Nested Destination List

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am new to AutoMapper and I'm looking to map a Nested List to my Parent DTO, here is my DTO:

```
    public class ParentDTO
    {
        //Other Members
        public List<HostInfo> HostInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class HostInfo
    {
        //Other Members
        public List<PluginInfo> Plugins { get; set; }
    }

    public class PluginInfo
    {
        //More Members
    }
```

Here is my Profile:

```
 public ParentProfile()
        {
           //Other Mappings
            
            CreateMap<Plugin, PluginInfo>().ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<Source, ParentDTO>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.HostInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => SourceLookUp.Select(x => x.Data))))

            .ForPath(dto => dto.HostInfo.Select(x=> x.Plugins), opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.SourceLookUp.Select(x => x.Plugin)))
        }
```

However the following line:

```
            .ForPath(dto => dto.HostInfo.Select(x=> x.Plugins), opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Source.SourceLookUp(x => x.Plugin)))
```

Creates this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Only member accesses are allowed. dto => dto.HostInfo.Select(x => x.Plugins) Arg_ParamName_Name

Here is my desired output:

```
#ParentDTO
{
  //other data,
  "hostInfo": [
    {
      //Other Data
      "Plugin": [
      {
        //Other Data
      },
      {
        //Other Data
      } 
      ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Here is my current output when removing the troubled code stated above:

```
#ParentDTO
{
  //other data,
  "hostInfo": [
    {
      //Other Data
      "Plugin": Null
 ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is my Source Class and other relevant classes/members, they are generated by Entity Framework using db-scaffold:

```
public partial class Source
    {
        public Source()
        {
            SourceLookUps = new HashSet<SourceLookUp>();
        }

        //Other Members
        public virtual ICollection<SourceLookUp> SourceLookUps { get; set; }
    }
```

Plugin Class:

```
public partial class Plugin
    {
        public Plugin()
        {
            SourceLookUps = new HashSet<SourceLookUp>();
        }

        //Other Members
        public virtual ICollection<SourceLookUps > SourceLookUps { get; set; }
    }
```

SourceLookUps Class

```
public partial class ScanLookUp
    {
        //Other Members
        public virtual Plugin Plugin { get; set; }
        public virtual Source Source{ get; set; }
    }
```

Finally, I interact with Auto Mapper using a .Net 6.0 WebAPI:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
       public ParentDTO Get(int id)
       {
           var data= _context.Source.First(x => x.Id == id);
           return _mapper.Map<ParentDTO>(data);
       }
```

Comment: Before start using Automapper, take a time to read when use it or not from it's creator [AutoMapper Usage Guidelines](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/)

Comment: In order to help, we need to see the whole picture, which means `Source` class and relevant members.

Comment: Still doesn't compile -> `SourceLookUp` and `ScanLookUp` classes missing, `Plugin` constructor invalid.

Comment: @IvanStoev Apologies ScanLookUp was a typo, updated, 2nd time lucky :P.

Comment: Ok, so as source you have 2 regular entities and 1 many-to-many join entity. `Source` maps to `ParentDTO`. However the two nested lists seem wrong (can't see how they map to the source model). `Source.SourceLookUps` list can be mapped to 1 List with elements mapped  from `Plugin` property of the join collection.  i.e. `Plugin` maps to `HostInfo`. There is no further collection to map. At least with this source entity model. In general, you should be able to write LINQ query with `Select`s to populate the DTO. Then AM can be configured to eliminate the obvious properties assignments inside.